# Cuda installation assumes wrong drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I try to install Cuda 8.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation. My graphics card is a GTX 760. The Nvidia driver that I am using is version 375.82 (Open Source). I also tried 384.69, but that causes my screen to flicker and I was not able to solve this, hence stick to 375. Proprietary drivers are not offered by Additional Drivers.

Now my issue is that when compiling the Cuda samples, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'cudaDecodeGL' failed
make[1]: *** [cudaDecodeGL] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/till/cuda_samples/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL'
Makefile:52: recipe for target '3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build' failed
make: *** [3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

It seems that there is a mismatch between the actual used driver version and the one expected by Cuda. The file `libnvcuvid.so` is found in `nvidia-384`-folders only:

```
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libnvcuvid.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libnvcuvid.so
```

This is the output of `sudo dmesg | grep NVRM`:

```
[    0.836713] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.82  Wed Jul 19 21:16:49 PDT 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
[    7.567492] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[    7.567493] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[    7.567493] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[    7.567494] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[    7.567495] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
[  225.362634] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  556.604479] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.482098] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.483700] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.484674] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.485522] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.513333] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.514678] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.515697] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.516702] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  732.594678] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.157169] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.158720] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.159643] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.160487] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.179644] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.180478] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.181106] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.181609] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
[  743.253289] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 384.69, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.82.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
```

`nvidia-smi` returns:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

As I mentioned, I cannot use the 384 driver due to the flicker issue. Is it possible to make cuda work with the 375 driver?

Comment: In 16.04, the 375.66 driver works fine.  Fix  the problem of "Additonal Drivers" not offering the proprietary drivers, install the recommended one, then install the deb file from nvidia.  The cuda package from the regular repositories should get the rest (toolkit, etc.).  Clean out all the old Nvidia stuff first, that can only interfere.

Comment: @ubfan1 There's no problem with Additional Drivers. The "problem" is all proprietary drivers appear as "open source" once you add a PPA. 375/384 are Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: Please post the results of echo $PATH and echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, maybe you just forgot to set them up.  No graphics PPAs are necessary to get the working 375.66.  Some samples may need an edit in a makefile to update 367 to 375, but only a few.